# How do I set the width for an IMG when streaming out to MS Word from ASP.Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, image, ms-word, stream

I'm streaming out to MS Word a document in HTML.  It's working fine and the document downloads and opens in Word as expected.  However, I'm on to my next trick and I want to include an Image in the file.  I don't know the exact size of the image, however, as it is variable based on the users upload.  So, I tried setting the image width as follows IMG Width=100px ...   but the image came into word at full size.  I also tried IMG style="width:100px" ... but the same result.  I also tried IMG style="width:10%" ... same problem.  I went to google but couldn't find anything useful on this.  Thought I would try reaching out to you folks.   Does anyone happen to know to set the width of an image when streaming to an MS Word document?

I also as a test took the output of the html string that gets sent to word, and put it in notpad, saved it as an htm file and took a look.  It's formatted correctly and the image is the correct size there.   So this seems to be something specific with how word handles image sizes, maybe?

Edit:  note that in my example below I am only showing the relevant HTML ... but the actual HTML sent out is correctly formatted with html and body tags and so on.

The code I am using looks like this:

```
Sub PrintItem()
   PrintToWord(strPrintOut)
End Sub

Function strPrintOut() as String
           If CTR.ImagePath <> "None" Then
                Dim PrintCTRImage As String = ""
                PrintCTRImage = "<table width=15%><tr><td><IMG style=""height:100px;float:left;"" SRC=" & Chr(34) & MySession.BC.GetIMGPath(CTR.ImagePath, True, pg) & Chr(34) & "></td></tr></table>"
                strCTRt &= PrintCTRImage
            End If
    strPrintOut = strCTRt 

End Function

Public Sub PrintToWord(ByVal strPrintOut As String, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal pg As Page)
            Try
                Dim bString() As Byte
                bString = StrToByteArray(strPrintOut)
                pg.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", FileName & ".doc"))
                pg.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName
                pg.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
                pg.Response.BinaryWrite(bString)
                pg.Response.Flush()
                pg.Response.End()
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

            Catch ex As System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
            Catch ex As Exception
                MySession.BC.HandleMessage(ex, pg)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... hunting and pecking randomly I found an unrelated post that clued me into the answer.  The code the build the image tag string should look like this:

```
PrintCharacterImage = "<HR><IMG width=""120"" Height=""120"" style=""float:left;Margin:12px;"" SRC=" & Chr(34) & MySession.BC.GetIMGPath(Character.ImagePath, True, pg) & Chr(34) & ">"
```

Comment: As always, everything is easy when you know what to do.